# setTimeout giving arguments to function from another function

Tags: javascript, function

Got a problem, don't know how can I give to ClickSimClick function arguments exposed by ClickSimMove func (it returns array with 2 values).

Code below says that crd is undefined on setTimeout.

```
var crd = plugin().ClickSimMove();
setTimeout("plugin().ClickSimClick(crd[0], crd[1])", 1000);
```

Comment: It depends on whether you want the value of crd[0] at the time you call setTimeout or the value at the time the timeout fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a function, not a string:

```
var crd = plugin().ClickSimMove();
setTimeout(function() {
    plugin().ClickSimClick(crd[0], crd[1]);
}, 1000);
```

When you pass a string, it's evaluated as it would be with `eval` in the global scope, losing all access to local variables. An anonymous function lets you reference any variable in scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
var crd = plugin().ClickSimMove();
setTimeout(function(){
  plugin().ClickSimClick(crd[0], crd[1]);
}, 1e3);
```

When at all possible, avoid sending strings to `setTimeout`/`setInterval`--use an anonymous function instead. Especially if you find yourself concatenating variables to make that string, you can run in to trouble very quickly with some sort of injection or malformed component.